# finite subgroups of discrete arithmetic groups

Tags: finite-groups, hyperbolic-geometry, arithmetic-groups

Let K be a totally real multi-quadratic fields and let $\mathcal{O}$ be its ring of integers. I would like to compute the orders of the finite subgroups of the discrete group $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathcal{O})$. These orders are helpful for computing Euler characteristics.

I would like to know whether there is any methods to do the computations and where to find them.
Thanks for all.

Comment: the finite subgroups are all abelian